# Jquery live blur and live focus

Tags: jquery, focus, live, blur

I am opening up a dialog box dynamically. When click on a link it looks for info and display it in it.

```
$('.comment').live('blur', function(){
    var split = (this.id).split("_");
    var id = split[1];

    $('#face_'+ id).fadeOut();
    $('.commentbutton').hide();
    $("#comments_" + id).slideDown();
})

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

// commentopen 
$(".comment").live("focus", function() { 
    var split = (this.id).split("_");
    var vmid = split[1]; 

    $("#face_" + vmid).fadeIn();
    $("#comments_" + vmid).slideUp();
    $('#commentbutton_' + vmid).show();

});
```

That works fine when you first open the dialog, but if you close it and try to open it again, it no longer works, at least in firefox.

When I put an alert it shows that the ID was sent. But why  `$('.commentbutton')` and `#face_' + vmid` no longer `fadeIn()`, `slideUp()`, `slideDown()` and blur function does nothing?

I also tried with focusin and focusout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

with the new versions of jquery live() is deprecated instead you should use on() (note the new format):

```
$(document).on('blur','.comment', function(){
   var split = (this.id).split("_");
   var id = split[1]; 
   $('#face_'+ id).fadeOut();
   $('.commentbutton').hide();
   $("#comments_" + id).slideDown();
});
         //////////////////////////////////////////////////

         // commentopen 
$(document).on("focus",".comment", function() { 
   var split = (this.id).split("_");
   var vmid = split[1]; 

   $("#face_" + vmid).fadeIn();
   $("#comments_" + vmid).slideUp();
   $('#commentbutton_' + vmid).show();

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: thanks, but nothing opens anymore. Here is the html I have for a comment box. When click on it it displays user avatar and submit button, when blur, it hides them.<div class="clear"></div>

Comment: <div class="clear"></div>
<div style="width:100%;">
<div id="commentbox_61" class="commentupdate commentouter">
<div id="face_61" class="stcommentimg" style="display:none;">
<img width="32" border="0" title="Lionel's Profile Picture" alt="" src="customprofilepics/profilepic1_1.gif">
</div>
<div class="stcommenttext link-input">
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea id="ctextarea_61" class="comment" maxlength="200" name="comment"></textarea>
<input id="commentbutton_61" class="commentbutton" type="button" value=" Comment" style="display:none;float:right;">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on({
    blur: function(){
        var id = this.id.split("_")[0];
        $('#face_'+id).fadeOut();
        $('.commentbutton').hide();
        $("#comments_"+id).slideDown();
    },
    focus: function() {
        var vmid = this.id.split("_")[1];
        $("#face_"+vmid).fadeIn();
        $("#comments_"+vmid).slideUp();
        $('#commentbutton_'+vmid).show();
    }
},'.comment');
```

Replace document with the closest non dynamic parent.
As for why it's not working on second click, that's really hard to answer without seeing more of the actual code.

Comment: here is a link. Use testuser passwd testdemo

Comment: http://www.vbcover.com/customdev/ihaiti/member.php?1-Lionel click on any top thumbs